# Angular velocity of disc attached to rod rotating about pivot

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum

[image]

Consider the following system moving of a disc attached to a rod pivoted to a point on the roof under the influence of gravity, with the disc free to rotate about end of rod and rod about pivot. It is found that in the motion that the disc doesn't spin, why is this?

As a contrasting question, if it was indeed the disc was indeed welded to the rod, then the disc would spin about.

I got this from the first problem discussed in this [site](https://www.concepts-of-physics.com/mechanics/physical-pendulum.php). I reread their explanation about angular momentum a few times and I just don't get it, hopefully someone can write a simpler/ clear explanation of why it should be.  I also found discussion of the problem in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQSkq0Y64wo)

Comment: What would happen if the disk was not attached to the rod and was pivoted about its center of mass? Why would that be any different from your situation?

Comment: If it was pivoted to COM... hmm I don't think it'd rotate

Comment: But doesn't the total gravity act at a different place @BillN (the combined COM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no torque applied to the disk (in theory). A round pin can only transfer reaction forces. By contrast, a square pin can transfer forces and torques.

[image: fig1]

For the round pin case, the contact forces are in line with the centerline of the disk causing all contact forces to be through the center of mass and thus cause translation only.

For the square pin case, the contact forces can be offset by a certain amount causes not only forces to act on the disk, but also a net torque about the disk center of mass.

The second situation is similar to the *welded* case.

In reality, there is friction which *is* going to spin the disk. So you choose the level of detail you want to examine.

Comment: Hey John, I didn't see this post earlier. I didn't quite get your answer because there are two different cases to consider here. One if the disc is welded and one if it isn't

Comment: If it is welded then the disk attachment can transfer torques as well as forces and thus the disk _will_ spin.

Comment: I think I am stuck on how the torques are transferred, could you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: ok see edit above.